# Is there any way to run web application after both Adobe and browsers are going to end Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, browser, cross-browser

I have got an update few months back that, [Adobe Flash is going to end after 2020](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/enterprise-end-of-life.html). I have a web application using Flash. I am aware I have very little time to upgrade the application to new technologies. Also, it looks like the Flash has internal timer which will detect the end of 2020. Here is what I have tried and got info:

1. Changed my system time to 2021 and tried to run. Application didn't load.
2. Is there any browser that going to run the Flash?
3. Does installing Adobe Flash on system locally, and running old version of browser in the system will work after 2020?
4. Is there any option in any of the browser to disable or enable to make the web application run?

Note: Got info from net that:

Info shared by Harman is going to support: [https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe#:~:text=HARMAN'S%20SUPPORT%20PROGRAM%20FOR%20ADOBE,hundreds%20of%20millions%20of%20systems.&text=HARMAN%20will%20offer%20support%20and,end%20of%202023%20and%20beyond](https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe#:%7E:text=HARMAN%27S%20SUPPORT%20PROGRAM%20FOR%20ADOBE,hundreds%20of%20millions%20of%20systems.&text=HARMAN%20will%20offer%20support%20and,end%20of%202023%20and%20beyond). - Is this free service? From where to download ?

What is the best ways to run flash used for web application after 2020?

Comment: You should make some elaborate tests on Flash Player not working in 2021. It is much more likely that sites refuse incoming requests because SSL-certificates are time-limited, than Flash Player actually has some inner date limit. Then, you might want to update your client to HTML5/JS with Adobe Animate and the same source files you have for your Flash client?

Comment: There are lots of other browser available apart from IE, Chrome, Safari and Firefox... So is there any other browser going to support flash after 2020? Is something is free and that can be used??

Answer (score 4):

on Windows, with the last Flash Player (32.0.0.445), you can change the file "mms.cfg" and configure some patterns to let the flash player works after the 12 january 2021 :

```
EOLUninstallDisable = 1
EnableAllowList = 1
AllowListUrlPattern = https://myurl.com/
AllowListUrlPattern = https://*.mysuburl.com:443/
```

The Flash Player version with the "kill switch" is the "32.0.0.387".
So if you use an older version of Flash Player on a "old" browser without doing updates, you could run Flash Player without problems.

You can read this to get more informations about "mms.cfg" :
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/pdf/latest/flash_player_32_0_admin_guide.pdf

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254243/does-the-flash-executable-itself-stop-flash-from-working-january-12-2021/65685790#65685790 for a more detailed solution